# At what offset does swiping trigger invoked event?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, swipeview

Using Xamarin Forms, I'm trying to understand at which offset during swiping will my SwipeView trigger the `Invoked` event when using mode `Execute` and if it's possible to programmatically get this value. So far what I've seen is it seems to be around 60% of `Threshold` (at least for Android) but I'm curious to know if this value is available somewhere in the component. I originally thought it wouldn't be triggered until it hit `Threshold` but I found that it fires before it meets that value. Below is my XAML:

```
<SwipeView
    SwipeChanging="SwipeView_SwipeChanging"
    SwipeEnded="SwipeView_SwipeEnded"
    SwipeStarted="SwipeView_SwipeStarted"
    Threshold="80">
    <SwipeView.TopItems>
        <SwipeItems Mode="Execute" SwipeBehaviorOnInvoked="Close">
            <SwipeItemView BackgroundColor="Transparent" Invoked="SwipeItemView_Invoked">
                <Label Text="Create New Task" />
            </SwipeItemView>
        </SwipeItems>
    </SwipeView.TopItems>
    <SwipeView.Content>
    ...
    </SwipeView.Content>
</SwipeView>
```

With the above example with `Threshold` at `80` it seems to trigger around 49/50.

Comment: Hmm, almost a factor of 2. Perhaps Threshold isn't in the units you expect? Should be based on Device Independent Pixels, not hardware pixels.

Comment: Forms is open source, you can always examine the code yourself